# ffmeg force keyframe at specific interval

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264

I'm using ffmpeg to split videos at certain interval intervals, as ffmpeg can just split the video on keyframes i do need to force extra keyframes at the interval i need.

my ffmpeg command runs fine on windows like:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i asd.mp4 -map 0 -segment_time 15 -f segment -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*15)" asd%03d.mp4
```

But when i try to run on linux i get:

```
Invalid duration specification for force_key_frames: "expr:gte(t
```

i tried to replace double quotes for simple quotes but same error

I'm using the exact same parameters on windows and linux [including same video file] just adjusting the ffmepg binary path.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Is there another way i can achieve this behavior?

Comment: `-force_key_frames expr:'gte(t,n_forced*15)'`

Comment: @Gyan didn't work... [Eval @ 0xbf94c7bc] Unknown function in 'gte(t,n_forced*15)'

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the new command and the complete log.

Comment: The `expr` feature was added in 2015. What is your ffmpeg version?

Comment: latest, compiled from source

Comment: Run with -report and share log.

Answer (score 2):

Had exact the same issue. Worked fine on my Linux machine, on Windows I got that error. After dropping the quotes it runs on Windows, in my example I changed:

```
-force_key_frames 'expr:gte(t,n_forced*10)'
```

to

```
-force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*10)
```